# JWT fastest algorithm

Tags: c#, .net, jwt

I'm working on a web application which uses this [JWT-library](https://github.com/dvsekhvalnov/jose-jwt) for security. I've noticed that a substantial amount of the server's CPU is being consumed by the JWT library working on token decryption. The current configuration is defined as shown below.

```
JweAlgorithm.PBES2_HS512_A256KW, JweEncryption.A256CBC_HS512
```

When testing, 1000 subsequent calls to this take **87s**. Fastest alternative that I've found is: `JweAlgorithm.PBES2_HS256_A128KW, JweEncryption.A128GCM`, taking **27s**.

Could you recommend something faster than that?

Comment: Cryptography is meant to be slow... Else you could brute force it.

Comment: Not necessarily, it all depends on ingenuity of algorithm. At least that was a promise of crypto - that you can have one-way function which is much slower to decode than to encode. I don't believe cryptography is meant to be slow.

Comment: This is not a password hashing algorithm like a PBKDF or brcypt. It does not have to be slow at all

Comment: If you can decode it, you can encode it. If time is not a factor, you have infinite time to decode it. If decoded you can encode it. So why not just use cleartext? Simple: Because time is a factor. And that's the reason why tokens have a life span.

Comment: Sure, it is about tradeoffs. And I'm asking what's the fastest algorithm that JWT has to offer.

Comment: You do not need to decode it on every request. You can cache it on the first request, if that is what you question is. But before thinking about caching, make sure, it's worth it, e. g. you identified the token as the hot spot (bottleneck, critical time consuming part of your application), which most likley it is not

Comment: i went for JweAlgorithm.DIR, JweEncryption.A128GCM. which required changing password from string to byte[], which is ofc small thing, but still annoyance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, algorithms with shared secret (symmetric) are faster compared to the one that use public/key pair (asymmetric).

The algorithm `PBES2-HS512+A256KW` is a symmetric algorithm, but it has a specificity: it has a [`salt`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7518#section-4.8.1.1) and an [`iteration count`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7518#section-4.8.1.2) parameters that `add computational expense` to be deliberately slow.

The RFC7518 recommended a minimum value of 1000 iteration whilst [OWASP](https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet.md) requires “a number implying that the computation time on the target system must take at least 1 second (like 1000.000 for example)”.

The efficiency of the algorithm mainly depends on the JWT implementation you use and the crypto tools behind this.
For PHP, some key encryption algorithms take only 400µs (e.g. ECDH-ES over X25519 curve) when other take more than 2.5ms (PBES2+HS384-A192KW with 512bits salt and 4096 iteration count).

I would recommend to run benchmarks to find the most appropriate algorithms for your use case and environment.

*“fastest” does not mean “safest”*